# typescript use preset value for property value in array object error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this simple typescript code for react

```js
type fruitCode = 'apple' | 'banana'

interface fruitList {
  name: fruitCode
}

const [arr, setArr] = useState<fruitList[] | []>([])

useEffect(() => {
  const arrList = [{
    name: 'apple'
  }, {
    name: 'banana'
  }];

  //error?
  setArr(arrList)
}, [])
```

demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-gi6fw?file=/src/App.tsx:103-391

how can I restrict my property value is either 'apple' and 'banana'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript cannot infer the type for `arrList` so set it directly

```js
const arrList: fruitList[] = [
  // ...
]
```

I would also remove `| []` from the state type definition as it is redundant; an empty array still satisfies the `<fruitList[]>` requirement.

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState<fruitList[]>([])
```

Finally, your interfaces and types should not be part of the component. Move them above `App`

```js
type fruitCode = "apple" | "banana";
interface fruitList {
  name: fruitCode;
}

export default function App() {
  // ...
}
```

You'll notice there are no warnings about your `useEffect` dependencies after this.

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Comment: why `useState<fruitList[] | []>([])` doesn't make sense? it can be empty array no?

Comment: @AliciaY any array type can be represented by an empty array, you don't need to include the empty array in the signature